# what is the core technology used in ejb's?

Tags: ejb

what is the core technology used in ejb's ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Um... Java? The expression "core technology" is far too vague to give a meaningful answer here.

Comment: well i was expecting a sub technology. Is it RMI ?

Comment: @user602774: RMI-IIOP is the default communication protocol used for remote EJB calls. It's one of a large number of technologies used in an EJB container. The word "technology" itself is used for so many completely different things these days that it has pretty much lost all meaning.